# How do I change the colour of directory listings with oh-my-fish?

Tags: fish

I've recently decided to give the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) a shot and also started using [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish). The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to change the color of directory listings when running a command such as `ls`. The picture attached below shows directories being listed in a dark blue and files listed in a gray.

[image]

I've tried changing the theme to no avail and I can't figure out where else to look. Any ideas?

Comment: What's oh-my-fish? the link is broken :(

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You are probably seeing the result of `LSCOLORS`, which you can look up in the ls man page or Google.

The reason that you see this with fish and not, say, bash, is that fish wraps ls in a function that passes the -G flag, as you can see:

```
> functions ls
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    command ls -G $argv
end
```

You can change LSCOLORS to be something else, e.g. on [OS X](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/issues/10):

```
set -Ux LSCOLORS gxfxbEaEBxxEhEhBaDaCaD
```

That makes a universal environment variable, so you just have to run it once.

Or you can disable it entirely by overwriting the function:

```
function ls ; command ls ; end
funcsave ls
```

This creates and saves a function `ls` that has priority over the bundled one.

Comment: Btw, in case anybody wonders, this will make your folders teal.

Comment: On Ubuntu the name of the environment variable is `LS_COLORS`. Note the underscore! `man dircolors` for more info.

Comment: It's better to "set -Ux LSCOLORS gxfxbEaEBxxEhEhBaDaCaD" directly in .config/fish/config.fish , not?

Comment: No, because the `set -Ux` stays permant without being in the config.fish file. indeed setting things over and over in the config file can lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

A little non programmatic solution:

If you use MacOS, you can change the purple via the terminal preferences. In there go to *Profile* and change the *ANSI Colors* setting.