# Fish Shell ls command directories are in unreadable purple

Tags: fish

When I run the `ls` command from my terminal using fish, the output of directories is a bold purple, which I can't read. I tried changing my color theme, but it did not affect the result of the `ls` command. How do I go about changing these colors?

Comment: This post has a helpful description on how to change the colors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560595/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-directory-listings-with-oh-my-fish

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default colour:

```
default=color
```

And then for example

```
lscolor fish=magenta js=cyan default=yellow
```